# Image is not displayed for avatar in browser - using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am newbie and trying to get hands-on working on a project. I have referred to the other questions but they are not similar to this. I am unsure what I am missing here.
I have imported the image in Component-1 and sending it as props to Component-2
here is my code

```
**Component-1** 

import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import HeaderOption from './HeaderOption';
import avatar from '../src/images/avatar.jpg';`enter code here`

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className='right_header'>
      <HeaderOption Icon={HomeIcon} title='Home' />
      <HeaderOption avatarIcon={avatar} title='Me' />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;


**component-2**

import React from 'react';
import './HeaderOption.css';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';

function HeaderOption({ avatarIcon, Icon, title }) {
  return (
    <div className='headerOption'>
      {Icon && <Icon className='headerOption_icon' />}
      {avatarIcon && (
        <AccountCircleIcon className='headerOption_icon' src={avatarIcon} />
      )}
      <h3 className='headerOption_title'>{title}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderOption;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you need is [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-avatar/):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

export default function ImageAvatars() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
      <Avatar alt="Travis Howard" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
      <Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg" />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

AccountCircleIcon is an icon and you can't change that. Therefore what you should do is this:

```
avatarIcon && <Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" className='headerOption_icon' src={avatarIcon} /> )}
```